# Why doesn't belongs_to have a restrict_with_exception option for dependent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model like:

```
class ImportedReceipt < ApplicationModel
  # dependent: :restrict_with_exception is not allowed on belongs_to
  belongs_to: :payment

  before_destroy :allow_destroy 

  def allow_destroy
    return false if payment
    true
  end
end
```

I want to disallow destroying an `ImportedReceipt` if it is linked to a `Payment`.

I can do this by returning `false` from a `before_destroy` action.

Is there a reason Rails doesn't allow `:restrict_with_exception` on `belongs_to` associations?

Comment: Maybe you can create a new issue in Rails Github Repository.

Comment: Is the association one to one? If its one to many you should not be declaring `dependent:` on the `belongs_to` side as that won't prevent orphaned records or create and infinite loop if you add it on both sides.